# is there a way to access / drain even the unexpired elements in a java DelayQueue

Tags: java

I have a use case where on the shutdown hook I want access all the elements in a DelayQueue even if the objects inside the queue are not yet expired (aka, you can't access them with poll, take or drainTo)

But on shutdown we are in this special use case where I just want to remove all the elements and write them to a store so one start up we can just re-add them to the queue.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Delayed` items are scheduled in a `ScheduledExecutorService`, you can get a list of them when using `shutdownNow()`:

```java
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable dummy = () -> System.out.println("Dummy operation");

    // ScheduledFuture implements Delayed
    ScheduledFuture<?> dummyHandle =
        scheduler.schedule(dummy, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    System.out.println("dummyHandle: " + dummyHandle);

    System.out.println("\nShutting down..");

    List<Runnable> myshotDownList = scheduler.shutdownNow();
    System.out.println("myshotDownList: " + myshotDownList);
  }
}
```

This will print:

```java
dummyHandle: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@5b94b04d[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@291caca8[Wrapped task = Test$$Lambda$185/0x00000001001b9440@385e9564]]

Shutting down..
myshotDownList: [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@5b94b04d[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@291caca8[Wrapped task = Test$$Lambda$185/0x00000001001b9440@385e9564]]]
```

---

As you noticed when the Delayed item is in an accessible `DelayQueue`, like this:

```java
    DelayQueue<Delayed> myDelayQueue = new DelayQueue<>();
    myDelayQueue.add(dummyHandle);
```

`poll()` will return "null":

```java
    System.out.println("Polling: " + myDelayQueue.poll());
```

`take()` will wait until it's ready and remove it from the queue. Which in this case is a long 10 minute wait:

```java
    try {
      System.out.println("Taking: " + myDelayQueue.take());
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      System.out.println("Got interrupted");   
    }
```

and `drainTo()` doesn't drain items not ready, so `myDrainedList` will be empty:

```java
    List<Delayed> myDrainedList = new ArrayList<>();
    myDelayQueue.drainTo(myDrainedList);
```

---

But since `DelayQueue` is a [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html), it can be used in the constructor of another `Collection`:

```java
    List<Delayed> myDelayedList = new ArrayList<>(myDelayQueue);
```

It can be also be iterated:

```java
    List<Delayed> myDelayedList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    myDelayQueue.forEach(e -> myDelayedList2.add(e));
```

Both the above lists will contain the `Delayed` element:

```java
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@5b94b04d[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@291caca8[Wrapped task = Test$$Lambda$185/0x00000001001b9440@385e9564]]
```